# Exception Handling Request through SSLError

Tags: python, error-handling

This is my function for checking link. But it throws an error when the link is fake. For example, it works for twitter.com but not for twitt.com.

```
class Quality_Check:
    def check_broken_link(self,data):
        url= requests.head(data)

        try:
            if url.status_code==200 or url.status_code==302 or url.status_code==301:
                return True
        except requests.exceptions.SSLError as e:
            return False

qc=Quality_Check()
print(qc.check_broken_link('https://twitte.com'))
```

When i try to handle the exception by this method it shows following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='twitte.com', 
port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, 
'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)'),))
```

and another one appeared too

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='twitte.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)'),))
```

Comment: So what is your question? How you can handle exceptions? How you can get your way of handling exceptions to work?

Comment: My question is how can I handle this exceptions ?

Comment: Sure, please see my answer below.

Comment: Did my answer work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exception happens on the `url= requests.head(data)` line. So you should include that line in `try` like so:

```
class Quality_Check:
    def check_broken_link(self,data):
        try:
            url = requests.head(data)
            if url.status_code == 200 or url.status_code == 302 or url.status_code == 301:
                return True
        except requests.exceptions.SSLError as e:
            return False

qc=Quality_Check()
qc.check_broken_link('https://twitte.com')
```

Returns `False`, and on `'https://twitter.com'` it returns `True`, which is the desired result.

---

And by the way, you can change your line of

```
if url.status_code == 200 or url.status_code == 302 or url.status_code == 301:
```

to

```
if url.status_code in (200, 302, 301):
```